# How can I know the linearity/nonlinearity from the FRF result?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

It's a FRF of neat PA 11 obtained by vibration test. (Mind that g is not a gram but the acceleration) Explanation says that for the excitation level of 5g, the FRF is strongly modified and the peak's shape highlights a nonlinear behaviour.

[image]

My question is,

1. How can I check the linearity from the plotted FRF result? Do I have to check it roughly by skewness of graph?
2. I've read that plotted FRF is linearized graph from somewhere else. Then is it correct to say that FRF can be obtained from "both" linear and nonlinear system but the result will "only" be linear? If so, how should I understand the "nonlinear behaviour of peak" part mentioned from the explanation?

Thank you.